# How to change the background color of navigationbar in ios6 and ios7 both?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar, uibackgroundcolor

How to change the background color of navigationbar in iOS6 and iOS7 both?i want to know when to use `setBarTintColor:` method and when to use `backgroundColor` to change the background color of navigationbar.

Please tell me the difference between these two methods.

And a way to change the background color of navigationbar in both ios6 and ios7.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

// *barTintColor* sets the background color
// *tintColor* sets the buttons color

Answer (score 0):

try this...i have refered this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) it supports for both iOS6 and iOS7

```
// Uncomment to change the background color of navigation bar
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x067AB5)];

    // Uncomment to change the color of back button
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // Uncomment to assign a custom backgroung image
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg_ios7.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // Uncomment to change the back indicator image

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"]];


    // Uncomment to change the font style of the title

    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                           shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

in ios6

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

in ios7

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

or

```
[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`barTintColor` = Applies to the navigation bar background. This one is only available for iOS 7. For iOS 6, you can use the tintColor.

`tintColor` = Applies to the navigation items and bar button items.

[Developer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barTintColor)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    // iOS 7.0 or later   
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}else {
    // iOS 6.1 or earlier
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

or

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        // iOS 6.1 or earlier
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        // iOS 7.0 or later     
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    }
}
```